# Issue to copy the content of magento website frontend

Tags: magento

I am facing problem to copy the content in magento website. I am able to right click and select the content but it is not paste the content. If i disable the javascript then i can copy the content. Please help me.

Comment: you answered yourself :), disable that relevant javascript which stops you from copying the content and remove it permanently if you don't need that.

Comment: if i disable the javascript it stops other things on website. i have tested it in developer tools.

Comment: does that js returns any error using developer tool like firebug in firefox?

Comment: in firebug not showing any js error.

Comment: try to find the specific function from that js which stops from copying.

Comment: is there any js to enable copy and paste description from website?

Comment: normally it doesn't happen in default site, its only happening because u have added a js for this purpose.

Comment: No, i did not add any js for this.

Comment: post the link of ur site. lets c if a quick help can be given.